# Can I charge the battery inside a Nikon D90 through the camera's USB port?

Tags: battery, nikon-d90, charger

I have to take some pictures, and brought my camera along. But the battery is empty, and it turns I have neither a second battery nor a charger.

I have a USB cable and access to a computer. If I connect the camera, will it charge the battery through the port? If yes, does it happen automatically, or do I have put it in charging mode somehow? Should the camera be turned on, turned off, or does it make no difference?

Answer (score 2):

No, it will not charge the battery.  USB Voltage is 5V and the camera battery is ~7.4.  They would have had to include a buck boost converter and other circuity in the camera just to allow for USB charging.

However, the D90 does have the DC IN jack on the side.  In the future, you'd be able to use an [EH-5a AC Adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0058OGZIY) to power/charge your camera.  Of course, if you are shooting in a remote location, or on the move, you likely won't be able to find a nearby wall outlet.

Comment: That AC adaptor would power the camera while it is plugged in, but will it actually charge the battery?

Comment: I was under the impression that it also charged the battery, but now you have me second guessing myself.  I haven't personally used the AC Adapter, so I can't say for sure.